# Registery keys in Users using .net service application

Tags: c#, service

I have tried to add some registery keys in c# service based application
but it does not work it does not give me any expection and does not create the key in registery.

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Settings");
key.SetValue("version", "0.0.0.1");
key.Close();
```

This service is running as system.

Comment: What exception is shown to you?

Comment: What user is the service running as?  Does the user have a login profile on the box?

Comment: i get no exceptions and the service is running as system user Thansk.